# Reversing XOR Encryption not working?

Tags: vb.net, encryption, xor

So I have the following function To XOR a string and it works but when I pass the encrypted string back into it the output is not decrypetd. MY understanding is to De XOR something is to simply XOR it again but it seems to fail, Any ideals on why this is ? Also Im storing the xor as hex

```
Public Shared Function StringToHash(ByVal str As String) As Integer
    Dim hash As Integer = (AscW(Char.ToLower(str(0))) Xor &H4B9ACE2F) * &H1000193
    For i As Integer = 1 To str.Length - 1
        hash = (AscW(Char.ToLower(str(i))) Xor hash) * &H1000193
    Next
    hash = hash * &H1000193
    Return hash
End Function
```

Comment: That is not encrytion but a weak hash.  Hashes as one way

Comment: ^^ Hashes **are** one way ^^

Comment: ffffs, So there isn't any way to reverse this ?

Comment: Nope, cant be reversed. But 2 xors do return a value to its original. If you're looking at rolling your own encrytion you should be converting the string to a byte array then for each element do the xor and return the byte array again. When you compress everything down into a single value it won't work. Better to just use an existing encryption method.

Answer (score 0):

As already indicated, this is about hashing, not encryption - two related but separate notions.

---

Although secure hashes are one-way, the above function is certainly not a secure hash. So you may be able to reverse it for very small input sizes.

Besides that, although hashes are usually not reversible, it may be possible to brute force the hash value.

This would only work for if the input alphabet is limited (a few characters, or a limited set of words etc.) and it may return too many inputs if the hash output size is small (which in this case it certainly is). But otherwise you just toss in some input and test if it results in the same hash value.

Comment: The strings I'm trying to Hash are about 5 - 15 charachters long and contain only A-z 1-0 and "_" Do you think I could brute fors one string within an hour ? And know of any example of brute force string generators?